# iOS7 SpriteKit how to group animations of two or more sprite node children?

Tags: animation, ios7, sprite-kit, skaction

**How can I create a SpriteKit animation for a node with multiple children and animate actions on multiple parts of the node as a group?**

I have the following node structure:

- Bird has children nodes for body, tail, head, etc
- Head has child nodes of upper beak, lower beak, etc

In the example below, I want to animate the entire bird with all children bending down to pick up a seed. During bending down, the bird opens its beak to eat the seed. Notice that the beak is not a child of the bird, it's a child of the head node.

```
//body does this action
    SKAction* bendDown = [SKAction rotateToAngle:M_PI*0.3 duration:lookUpTiming];

//beak does this action
    SKAction* openBeak = [SKAction rotateToAngle:-M_PI*0.175 duration:beakDuration + arc4random()%20/100.0];

//I need both actions to be  played together as a group:
    SKAction* bendAndOpenBeak = [SKAction group:@[bendDown, openBeak]];


    //if I call this, the body will perform both actions. 
    [self runAction:bendAndOpenBeak completion:^{

    }];
```

Here's the code that I can run on the head node to have it's children perform an action using `runAction:onChildWithName:` However, I need to run this as a group with the body (a parent of a parent) node

```
-(SKAction*)openBeak
{
    float angleUp = -M_PI*0.175;
    float duration = beakDuration + arc4random()%20/100.0;

    SKAction* rotateUp = [SKAction rotateToAngle:angleUp duration:duration];
    rotateUp.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;

    SKAction* rotateDown = [SKAction rotateToAngle:-angleUp duration: duration];
    rotateUp.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;


   return  [SKAction group:@[[SKAction runAction:rotateUp onChildWithName:@"beakUpper"],
                      [SKAction runAction:rotateDown onChildWithName:@"beakLower"] ]];

}
```

Comment: you need to show more to get real answers

Comment: self is the body of the bird

Comment: Did you get solution fro this problem?

Comment: @rptwsthi I just posted a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

`[SKAction runAction:onChildWithName:]` has an instantaneous duration, and so your group action won't wait for its completion.

The simple way to get the group to wait for all actions to complete is to add an `[SKAction waitForDuration:]` to the group, and use the duration property of the action passed into `[SKAction runAction:onChildWithName:]`

So in your example the code needed looks like this

```
-(SKAction*)openBeak {
  float angleUp = -M_PI*0.175;
  float duration = beakDuration + arc4random()%20/100.0;

  SKAction* rotateUp = [SKAction rotateToAngle:angleUp duration:duration];
  rotateUp.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;
  SKAction* waitForRotateUp = [SKAction waitForDuration:rotateUp.duration];

  SKAction* rotateDown = [SKAction rotateToAngle:-angleUp duration: duration];
  rotateUp.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseOut;
  SKAction* waitForRotateDown = [SKAction waitForDuration:rotateDown.duration];

  return  [SKAction group:@[[SKAction runAction:rotateUp onChildWithName:@"beakUpper"],
                  [SKAction runAction:rotateDown onChildWithName:@"beakLower"],
                  waitForRotateDown, waitForRotateUp]];

}
```

I've used the SKActions duration property in the example above even though your explicitly setting duration values as this approach can be used for actions such as sprite animations, where the duration isn't explicitly set.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `group`, just run them separately on each node, one by one:

```
//body does this action
SKAction* bendDown = [SKAction rotateToAngle:M_PI*0.3 duration:lookUpTiming];

//beak does this action
SKAction* openBeak = [SKAction rotateToAngle:-M_PI*0.175 duration:beakDuration + arc4random()%20/100.0];

[bodyNode runAction:bendDown];
[beakNode runAction:openBeak];
```

Comment: I need to repeat the sequence 3 times, so if I run actions in parallel, I need to do all kinds of calculations to make sure their timings are in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to exactly what you asked. This answer uses Swift 3.

```
import SpriteKit

class Scene: SKScene {
  // 1
  let lookUpTiming = 0.2
  let beakDuration = 0.2

  // 2
  let body = SKNode()
  let beak = SKNode()

  override func sceneDidLoad() {
    // 3
    let bendDown = SKAction.run {
      let action = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: .pi * 0.3, duration: self.lookUpTiming)
      self.body.run(action)
    }
    // 4
    let openBeak = SKAction.run {
      let duration = self.beakDuration + Double(arc4random_uniform(20)) / 100
      let action = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: -.pi * 0.175, duration: duration)
      self.beak.run(action)
    }
    // 5
    let group = SKAction.group([bendDown, openBeak])
    // 6
    run(group)
  }
}
```

Here's what's happening in this code:

1. Initialize the settings
2. Initialize the nodes
3. Create an SKAction for the first animation
4. Create an SKAction for the second animation
5. Create a group of those two actions
6. Run the group from the scene. Both animations will fire together even though they're on different nodes!